# Postman batch test adds query parameter

Tags: postman

I am using Postman for testing. I have a bunch of tests in a collection, and when I run each test individually, it works by POSTING to `http://localhost/v2/scores` or something like that. However, when I try to run the tests in batch, the requests get a query parameter added to it like so: `http://localhost/v2/scores?test=TRUE`, which causes the tests to fail. How do I run the batch tests without the query parameter?

A sample request is printed below:

```
"info": {
    "name": "mv:2017-09-14-hardscore tests",
    "_postman_id": "21f1d0f5-aa1f-efb8-3029-3c8609c40f66",
    "description": "",
    "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.0.0/collection.json"
},
"item": [
    {
        "name": "INTL XPN KO not in 38/39/40",
        "event": [
            {
                "listen": "test",
                "script": {
                    "type": "text/javascript",
                    "exec": [
                        "// Body Checks",
                        "tests[\"1. Fraudshield outsort exists\"] = responseBody.has(\"xpn_fraudshield\")",
                        "",
                        "// Value Checks",
                        "var resp = JSON.parse(responseBody);",
                        "tests[\"2. Should not be approved\"] = resp.approval === false;",
                        "tests[\"3. Knockout reason should be fico-aa 08\"] = resp.reason === 'XPN_FICO_AA008';",
                        ""
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "request": {
            "url": {
                "raw": "http://localhost/v2/scores",
                "protocol": "http",
                "host": [
                    "localhost"
                ],
                "path": [
                    "v2",
                    "scores"
                ],
                "query": [
                    {
                        "key": "test",
                        "value": "TRUE",
                        "equals": true,
                        "description": "",
                        "disabled": true
                    }
                ],
                "variable": []
            },
            "method": "POST",
            "header": [],
            "body": {
                "mode": "formdata",
                "formdata": [
                    {
                        "key": "body",
                        "value": "{\"test_frequency_withdrawal\": true, \"last_name\": \"Senevirathne\", \"ver_visa\": true, \"ver_esl\": true, \"major_grad\": \"\", \"ver_phone\": true, \"bal_closing\": 972, \"funds_excess\": 726, \"first_name\": \"Liyanage Thilanka\", \"uuid\": \"v2-130d0130-1424-4ae4-abe1-03060077eb47\", \"funds_total_i20_term\": 9, \"funds_total\": 21986, \"rank_underg\": \"EL\", \"bal_opening\": 972, \"test_frequency_transfer\": true, \"on_campus_employment_funds\": 0, \"plaid_connected\": true, \"test_transactions_max_daily\": true, \"level_of_study\": \"underg\", \"rank_grad\": \"\", \"funds_school\": 1000, \"ver_email\": true, \"ver_address\": true, \"funds_personal\": 0, \"cip_code_major1\": \"14.1901\", \"major_underg\": \"EN\", \"ver_passport\": true, \"model_version\": \"hardscore\", \"type\": \"INTERNATIONAL\", \"bureau_record_exists\": true, \"bureau\": \"EXPERIAN\",\"xpn_ALL2116\": \"00000000\", \"xpn_ALL2387\": \"00000000\",\"xpn_ALL2840\": \"00000000\",\"xpn_ALL2870\": \"00000000\", \"xpn_COL8197\": \"00000000\", \"xpn_ALL2704\": \"00000000\", \"xpn_fico_score_factor_code_one\": \"08\", \"xpn_fico_score_factor_code_two\": \"00\", \"xpn_fico_score_factor_code_three\": \"41\", \"xpn_fico_score_factor_code_four\": \"03\",\"xpn_fsvc_indicators\": [\"06\", \"  \", \"  \"], \"xpn_ALL5820\": \"000000\", \"xpn_MTA5830\": \"000000\",\"xpn_REV5320\": \"000000\",\"xpn_REV0416\": \"000000\",\"xpn_FICOv8\": \"000700\", \"xpn_mla_covered\": true, \"date_of_birth\": \"1992-12-01\" }",
                        "type": "text",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "description": ""
        },
        "response": []
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is in the body of your  scores request, and are there any entries listed when you click params?

Comment: What's in your request body  ? could you show it in runner pls ?

Comment: The body itself doesn't matter. The issue is the query parameter ?test=TRUE keeps getting added. I've since just deleted that query parameter, so I can't show you. But I know for a fact that the issue could be resolved if I could turn off all the query parameters in the runner.